# Docker Images are not working properly

Tags: python, django, docker

I am working on a python,django application. when i run application locally it works fine.But after building the docker images for same code and running the application with docker-compose up it works but some feature of application are not working as they work while running locally.

My application is document based application. while running locally it shows the image for document but in case of application run with docker images it does not show document images. Screen shots are attached.

is there any conflict with docker version which is causing problem.
Docker version is:
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

any help will b greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.[https://ibb.co/m2CUoT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fupH.png)

[https://ibb.co/cPTfv8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHw0M.jpg)

Comment: I don't think you uploaded the correct images. :-/ Also, consider reading this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I had simmilar problems and it tured out that it had to do with the permissions un the unix file system... Just a thought

Comment: check the docker logs using `docker logs <container id>` or check for any console errors in chrome

Comment: I checked the logs it shows some error, but these errors are just in case of docker images not while running application locally.@chakri

Comment: is there any database issue. i am using postgres as db.